# Lift Web Framework DRY dispatch

Tags: scala, dry, dispatcher, lift

I have an Image class:

```
class Image extends LongKeyedMapper[Image] with IdPK with Logger {
```

which overrides toHtml method:

```
override def toHtml =
  <img src={"/gallery/image/%s/%s/%s/%s" format (slug.is, "fit", 100, 100)} />
```

and it works beacause of this:

```
def dispatch = {
    LiftRules.dispatch.append {
        case Req("gallery" :: "image" :: slug :: method :: width :: height :: Nil, _, _) => {
            () => Image.stream(slug, method, width, height)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this is **not DRY** approach, since you have to define the URL (/gallery/image) twice.

Is it possible to make it DRY? Can you get the path from LiftRules or something?

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Comment: I don't know anything about Lift, but I don't see this as repeating yoursef. I see it more like `val a = "foo"; println(a)`, well I do mention `a` twice, once to say what `a` does and once to call it. I guess there is room for error in the way that the URL string is created but it's still simple enough...

Comment: There something I like in Django - HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('arch-summary', args=[1945])). The reverse method is something I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was answered by [David Pollak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243300/david-pollak#qpage_1-anpage_1-qsort_votes-ansort_recent) on the lift list:

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/liftweb/VG0uOut9hb4/discussion

In short, you:

encapsulate the things in common (in this case, the path) in an object:

```
object ImageGallery {
  val path = "gallery" :: "image" :: Nil
  val pathLen = path.length
  def prefix = path.mkString("/", "/", "/")
}
```

create a custom unapply method that allows you to use the object in the pattern match in your dispatch method.

```
object ImageGallery {
  // ...
  def unapply(in: List[String]): Option[List[String]] = 
    Some(in.drop(pathLen)).filter(ignore => in.startsWith(path))
}
```

Your code is now:

```
<img src={ImageGallery.prefix+"%s/%s" ...}>
```

...and:

```
case Req(ImageGallery(slug :: method :: width :: height :: _), _, _) => // ...
```

See the message thread for more suggestions.